# How do I tell what kind of object is being passed to a function in powershell other than Get-Member?

Tags: powershell

I have two examples, one works because it is literal, and the other is a function and doesn't work.

The goal is to return $true if the path exists, however in my function it always returns false.

```
$keyToDelete = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-1202660629-261903793-682003330-60470"
$SuppliedKeyExists = Invoke-Command -computername $UserComputerName {Test-Path $args[0]} -ArgumentList $keyToDelete

write-host $SuppliedKeyExists
```

This code works, where this code does not:

```
$UserComputerName = PC1
$UserProfileToRebuild = user1

function Get-KeyToDelete($UserComputerName, $UserProfileToRebuild){

    $WmiPathAndSID1 = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $UserComputerName -scriptblock {Get-WmiObject win32_userprofile | Select-Object localpath, sid}
    $WmiPathAndSID2 = $WmiPathAndSID1 | Select-Object localpath, sid | Where-Object {$_.localpath -contains "C:\Users\$UserProfileToRebuild"}

    $profileSID = $WmiPathAndSID2.sid | Out-String

    $keyToDelete = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$profileSID"
    return "$keyToDelete"
    
    }

function Check-KeyToDelete($UserComputerName, $keyToDelete){ ##function checks for .bak/corrupted user profiles first

        Write-Host $UserComputerName
        Write-Host $keyToDelete
        
        $SuppliedKeyExists = Invoke-Command -computername $UserComputerName {Test-Path $args[0]} -ArgumentList $keyToDelete

        Write-Host $SuppliedKeyExists
        
        function validateKey($keyToDelete){
        Write-Host "Validating key $keyToDelete"
        if ($keyToDelete.length -ne 110)
        {
        return "Invalid registry key selected for deletion, catastrophic execution, stopping program"
        exit
        }
        else{Write-Host "The length of the registry key is valid at 110 characters. Proceeding with program."}
        }

    
    $CorruptedKeyExists = Invoke-Command -computername $UserComputerName {Test-Path $args[0]} -ArgumentList "$keyToDelete.bak"

    Write-Host $SuppliedKeyExists

    if($SuppliedKeyExists){
    validateKey
    return $keyToDelete 
    }
    else{return "This Process Failed"}
}

Get-KeyToDelete $UserComputerName $UserProfileToRebuild

Check-KeyToDelete $UserComputerName $keyToDelete
```

The Write-Hosts in the second block are to verify what is being sent. $keyToDelete | get-member returns a string object and is apparently no different than just typing the string itself. So what is the difference in object type when I get it using a function, versus manually entering it?

Comment: If one function sets a local variable inside of it, then a second function will not know about that variable unless that second function is called within the previous function. This is how scoping works. You can override that by declaring the required scope for said variable. As for checking the type, most objects have a `GetType()` method. You can call `$keyToDelete.GetType()` as an example. Running `$keyToDelete = Get-KeyToDelete $UserComputerName $UserProfileToRebuild` before `Check-KeyToDelete $UserComputerName $keyToDelete`  will probably give you a better result.

Comment: @AdminOfThings GetType or gm both confirm that it's still passing a string, and as I use 'return' in the first function, I have verified that the value of the variable is what I intend it to be with the first write-host, and I've verified with Get-Member. I think the issue may be with something left over from this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/test-path-we-goofed/

However I'm not really sure.

Comment: Also, `Out-String` without `-NoNewLine` appends a blank line at the end of the output. That probably has unwanted side effects. The `.sid` property will return a string anyway so I'd remove `Out-String` completely.

Comment: Nowhere in your second script are you setting `$keyToDelete` so that it will have data when `Check-KeyToDelete $UserComputerName $keyToDelete` is called.

Comment: @AdminOfThings You'll just have to trust me when I say, $keyToDelete IS being set by the first function because my code does execute and pull the value I need.

I did manage to fix the issue by cutting out Out-String, and adding quotes around the ArgumentList. 

```
$SuppliedKeyExists = Invoke-Command -computername $UserComputerName {Test-Path $args[0]} -ArgumentList "$keyToDelete" 
```

This ended up solving it, and the rest of the function works without issue now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this myself by doing this:

```
$SuppliedKeyExists = Invoke-Command -computername $UserComputerName {Test-Path $args[0]} -ArgumentList "$keyToDelete"
```

I also removed the line with Out-String, which @AdminOfThings pointed out was causing a new line to be added to the var $keyToDelete

Thanks!